# AWS WorkMail API to get a message list or the last email

Tags: amazon-workmail

I need to write the e2e test for the next scenario:

Send invitation email with enrollment link to a specific mailbox
Find this email from the mailbox, parse the email body in order to get the enrollment link to follow the link end complete the enrollment process

In order to get the email, I want to use Amazon WorkMail, I want to use API to get a message list or the last email

for example:

const email = await AWS.SomeMailLibrary.fetchLatestEmail(emailAddress)

I haven't found yet if AWS WorkMail had API I need, Would you mind helping me with it?

thanks

Comment: I am looking at it for the same thing. Nothing I know of. In my case, I'm wanting to validate email address, but instead I'm just generating a validation link and manually opening it, rather than going to the official email.

Comment: Did you try using impersonation role for workmail?